# SQLite Syntax Error Flagged in Android Studio on rowid

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

In Android Studio 3, the `rowid` column is underlined and flagged as the followig error:

> column definition name expected, got 'rowid'

In Android Studio 2.3, I wasn't obtaining this syntax error. Meanwhile, the code still compiles and the app runs properly. Why is this syntax flagged as an error?

```
"create table myTable " +
                    "(rowid int primary key not null, field2 text, field3 int)"
```

Comment: Replacing `int` with `integer` would be [more correct](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowid` is the alias name that [can always be used](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), regardless of the actual column name, so it appears that Android Studio treats it as a keyword, although it is not actually one.

This looks like a (harmless) bug in Android Studio.

In any case, many Android framework classes expect the key column to be named `_id`, so you should probably use that instead of `rowid`.